# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot' | Works in Jupyter Notebooks but not VSCode

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, modulenotfounderror, python-camelot

Goal: to get a working version of this [tutorial](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-pdf-tables-in-python-camelot) with [PDF](https://github.com/x4nth055/pythoncode-tutorials/blob/master/general/pdf-table-extractor/foo.pdf), via. Visual Studio Code.

I am trying to install `camelot`, via. **VSCode**, using Poetry, but am having dependency problems.

This works in **Jupyter Notebooks** (bottom of post), but I am attempting to append to an existing .py project.

**Code:**

```
import glob
import camelot
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp

import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
find_library("".join(("gsdll", str(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp) * 8), ".dll")))


PDF_LIST = glob.glob('../data/gri/reports/*.pdf')

def scrape_tables(pdf_filename):
    tables = camelot.read_pdf(pdf_filename)
    print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)
    return tables

p = mp.Pool(len(PDF_LIST))
pdf_esg_scraped = p.map(scrape_tables, PDF_LIST)
```

`pip install camelot-py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_tables.py", line 25, in <module>
    import camelot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot'
```

`pip install camelot`:

```
danielbellhv@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/data_simulator/src$ pip install camelot
^[[A^[[A
Requirement already satisfied: camelot in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (12.6.29)
Requirement already satisfied: Elixir>=0.7.1 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from camelot) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy<0.8.0,>=0.7.7 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from camelot) (0.7.10)
Requirement already satisfied: xlrd==0.7.1 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from camelot) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.5.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from camelot) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: xlwt==0.7.2 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from camelot) (0.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy-migrate>=0.7.1 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from camelot) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=1.0.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from camelot) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sqlalchemy-migrate>=0.7.1->camelot) (5.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=1.8 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sqlalchemy-migrate>=0.7.1->camelot) (5.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Tempita>=0.4 in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sqlalchemy-migrate>=0.7.1->camelot) (0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from sqlalchemy-migrate>=0.7.1->camelot) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from sqlalchemy-migrate>=0.7.1->camelot) (0.4.2)
```

---

**Attempted Solution:**

I got Ghostscript filepath output in Jupyter Notebook.

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
find_library("".join(("gsdll", str(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp) * 8), ".dll")))
>>> 'C:\\Users\\me\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\gsdll64.dll'
```

Using this output, I need to ["append new location to the PATH variable"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69008991/16105404).

However, this does not work still. Variations I have tried:

```
PATH=$PATH:C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Library\bin\gsdll64.dll
PATH=$PATH:C:\\Users\\me\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\gsdll64.dll
PATH=$PATH:'c/Users/me/Anaconda3/Library/bin/gsdll64.dll'
PATH=$PATH:'/mnt/c/Users/me/Anaconda3/Library/bin/gsdll64.dll'

export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH";C:/Users/me/Anaconda3/Library/bin/gsdll64.dll
bash: C:/Users/me/Anaconda3/Library/bin/gsdll64.dll: No such file or directory
```

Further, in order to get **Poetry** to work, I need to have `PATH` point to its location:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

Can I have multiple `PATH` variables?

Comment: Getting VS Code to use the same Python version and library path as your system is a common FAQ. Please search before asking.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. In any case, by `pip install camelot` you are not installing Camelot tables extraction tool, but another package. The correct installation command is  `pip install camelot-py` (see https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html).

Comment: Will try `pip install camelot-py`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_tables.py", line 25, in <module>
    import camelot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot'`